# XCode 12 error Abort trap:6 when downgrading from XCode 13 beta 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have a project that was created on XCode 12. Next I opened it in XCode 13 beta 5 and made lot of edits. It builds fine on XCode 13 beta. Now it does not build at all in XCode 12.5. I tried clean build but still doesn't work. I wonder how do I build it with XCode 12? Worse, Build for Profiling succeeds but not the normal Build.

```
     <unknown>:0: error: fatal error encountered during compilation; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project
  <unknown>:0: note: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
  Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.

          Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
      1.    Apple Swift version 5.4 (swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55)

      2.    Running pass 'Module Verifier' on function '@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxH0OSo014AVAsynchronousA18CompositionRequestCtF"'

    0  swift-frontend           0x000000010796fe85 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 37

  1  swift-frontend           0x000000010796ee78 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 248

  2  swift-frontend           0x0000000107970446 SignalHandler(int) + 262

   3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff204fbd7d _sigtramp + 29

    4  libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff204d0ce8 _dyld_fast_stub_entry(void*, long) + 65

    5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff2040b406 abort + 125

     6  swift-frontend           0x0000000102b92a31 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*)::$_1::__invoke(void*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) + 1169

  7  swift-frontend           0x00000001078c52d0 llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) + 288

   8  swift-frontend           0x00000001078c51ab llvm::report_fatal_error(char const*, bool) + 43

   9  swift-frontend           0x000000010786537f (anonymous namespace)::VerifierLegacyPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 111

   10 swift-frontend           0x00000001077ff0b9 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 1353

    11 swift-frontend           0x00000001077fe3a0 llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Function&) + 112

    12 swift-frontend           0x0000000107805835 llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManager::run(llvm::Function&) + 341

   13 swift-frontend           0x0000000102f3e3e8 swift::performLLVMOptimizations(swift::IRGenOptions const&, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*) + 1688

   14 swift-frontend           0x0000000102f3f486 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions const&, swift::DiagnosticEngine&, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, llvm::StringRef, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 2582

   15 swift-frontend           0x0000000102b9e863 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 3683

    16 swift-frontend           0x0000000102b8fd22 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6370

   17 swift-frontend           0x0000000102b11e82 main + 1266

   18 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff204d1f3d start + 1

   error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'MyTarget' from project 'MyProject')
```

Comment: Backup? Version control system?  Wait for Xcode 13 to be released?

Comment: Uff, I want to test it with official version. Good news is that I can build and run release version but not debug version.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use a Swift 5.5 only feature while developing using Xcode 13 ?

Comment: I didn't use, but who knows frameworks may be using it.